# Unable to get extras in an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am putting extras with an intent from a service to an Activity like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, anc.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("abc", 100);
...
startActivity(intent);
```

and in
**Activity A**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String abc = extras.getString("abc");
```

When I debug this program, I can see `bundle` has extras but I cant assign it to `String` dont know why? 
I tried with `android:launchMode="standard"` for Activity A too.

I know I must be making very small mistake, but I am not getting to the problem at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have to do that :

```
intent.putExtra("abc", "100");
```

if you want to get a string. Dont forget these quotes : "..."

Also refer this link : [Android Intent Put Extra](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/)

Comment: Extras are passed alright. But not assigning to String. I checked by Debugging.

Comment: as i said you are trying to get it with extras.getString(); And putting into it a INT value that's why you couldn't get it. When you are putting them use quotes **(" ")**

Comment: yes, they are passed as integer : intent.putExtra("abc", 100); 100 is an Integer here. If you really want to get manipulate it as a string, you need to use "100" instead. Note that if you only need an int value, no need to convert it to string.

Comment: @Sercan ok I will this. What If I want to put some variable here then? `String abc = "test"` then `intent.putExtras("abc", abc);`

Comment: Then your variable type is important. If you are trying to put an Integer value use that code when getting it : getIntent().getExtras().getInt("abc")

Comment: @Sercan basically I want to get double values too. I am trying this `intent.putExtras("d1", doubleValueVariable)` and then `getIntent().getExtras.getDouble("d1")` but I am bot getting abything here. `String` though worked.

Comment: Are you sure it's a double variable ?  newActivity.putExtra("DOUBLE", Double.parseDouble(getText(R.string.LAT1)));

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
intent.putExtra("abc", String.valueOf(100));
```

Comment: what is the difference between doing this and using the "100" suggested in the first answer?

Comment: then you can use an integer variable here